# Loop a RecursiveIteratorIterator from an extended RecursiveIterator with extra arguments

Tags: php, iterator, spl

Let's say I have following `ArrayObject`:

```
$array_object = new ArrayObject(array(
   array('1', '2', '3', '4'),
   array('3', '6', '7', '8'),
   array('9', '3', '11', '12'),
));
```

And I extend `RecursiveFilterIterator` to accept only children elements which value is equal to some value passed in an argument:

```
class myRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
   public $value;

   public function __construct($it, $value)
   {
      parent::__construct($it);
      $this->value = $value;
   }

   public function accept()
   {
      return (parent::hasChildren()) || (parent::current() == $this->value);
   }
}
```

I create an instance of this brand new iterator, to filter values equal than 3:

```
$recursive_filter_iterator = new myRecursiveFilterIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array_object), 3);
```

If now I loop the whole `myRecursiveFilterIterator` using an `RecursiveIteratorIterator`:

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_filter_iterator) as $value) {
   var_dump($value);
}
```

I get following warning:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for myRecursiveFilterIterator::__construct() in /my/path/test.php on line myLine Notice: Undefined variable: value in /my/path/test.php on line myOtherLine
```

So it'is like when looping `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is trying to instance `myRecursiveFilterIterator` without passing second argument `$value`.

This doesn't happen if I extend `FilterIterator` without supplying extra arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to run the script my self and this is what have noticed

1. you are working with multi array so `parent::current()` can be an array that means that 
   the line below is wrong because `$this->value` is an integer.

   ```
   return (parent::hasChildren()) || (parent::current() == $this->value);
   ```
2. `$this->current ()` also switches String to Array you can do this to manage both depending on what you want to achieve

   ```
   if (is_array ( $current )) {
       return ($this->hasChildren ()) || (in_array ( ( string ) $this->value, $this->current () ));
   } else {

       //var_dump ( $this->value, $this->current () );

       return ($this->hasChildren ()) || ( $this->value == $this->current ());
   }
   ```
3. You also need to implement `getChildren` method that is why PHP was complaining about Missing argument 2 for `myRecursiveFilterIterator::__construct()`

   ```
   public function getChildren() {
       return new self ( $this->getInnerIterator ()->getChildren (), $this->value );
   }
   ```

============================== DISCARD OLD RESPONSE =============================

PHP most have communicated a wrong error message .. your code fine but the error originated when you tried to use foreach with RecursiveIteratorIterator directly

Here is a better approach using RecursiveArrayIterator to encapsulate RecursiveIteratorIterator :

```
foreach (new RecursiveArrayIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($recursive_filter_iterator)) as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Baba, but this doesn't work. The warning disappear, but nothing is looped (neither `$value` is var_dumped nor anything is echoed if tried)

Comment: Instead of give you alternative i decided to actually find the reason for your error ... see updated answer

Comment: Great @Baba!!! That works! So the trick was in the `getChildren()` method... :) Thank you very much.